# Error executing Junit from ubuntu Terminal

Tags: java, junit

I am trying to run Junit test from ubuntu terminal. My junit-4.10.jar and the package(grand.big.small) that contains the code are in the src folder.
I am able to compile and run my application using the following command from the src folder

```
javac grand/big/small/Main.java
java -cp . grand/big/small/Main
```

But cannot compile and run the junit test which reside in the same package(grand.big.small)
I am running the following command to execute them

```
javac -cp . :.junit-4.10.jar  grand/big/small/MainTest.java
```

I am getting the following error:

```
javac: invalid flag: :.junit-4.10.jar
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

I am new to this, could anyone please tell me where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A few issues

- javac compiles Java. `java` is used to run the compiled bytecode
- Extra space between `.` and the JAR file in the classpath
- You need to use `.` to reference packages at runtime

Since you're attempting to run a `JUnit` rather than execute an application, the run command would be

```
java -cp .:.junit-4.10.jar org.junit.runner.JUnitCore grand.big.small.MainTest
```

Comment: I ran you command and now it has given me the following error. I am confused now because we do not create main method in the Junit test 

Error: Main method not found in class grand.big.small.MainTest, please define the main method as:
   public static void main(String[] args)
or a JavaFX application class must extend javafx.application.Application

Comment: Thank you so much. Your help really means a lot to me.